# How to generate an RSS feed document?

Tags: go, rss

I need to generate an RSS feed in Golang. When looking for RSS-related libraries I mostly find libraries for parsing RSS feeds but not for generating them. The only one I did find is https://github.com/gorilla/feeds which I can't use because it doesn't allow me to add an image to the RSS items:

```
<media:content url="https://example.com/image.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

I can't use json feeds either, the intended client doesn't support those.

What would you recommend?

Comment: You could always fork `gorilla/feeds` and add image support.

Comment: If I try that, how do I use the forked library in my project?

Comment: RSS is a really simple format. Why not just use `encoding/xml` with a couple of user-defined `struct` types?

Comment: While we're at it, [the language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang)—mostly by the same logic we do not have JavaLang or PythonLang.

Comment: Running [this search query](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=rss) finds at least two RSS packages with "write" support.